# Sending Java server data to a React front end

Tags: java, reactjs, api, frontend, backend

**Here is what I've done so far:** There is an API (Hacker News - https://github.com/HackerNews/API) from which I send a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request from my Java program and retrieve the data. I am able to parse the (JSON) data so that it can be manipulated by the JDK.

**Here is what am trying to do next:** I want to have my Java program/server communicate with my React application so that React can retrieve the parsed JSON data and display it on a webpage.

**Confusion:** How do I have React get the data? Do I set it up so that it sends a GET request from my Java server? I have consulted more tutorials than I can count, but I am simply not understanding how to do it.

My code can be found here https://github.com/EmekaEnshinyan/HackerNews-API-Design-Back-End

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your React application is the frontend, and the Java program is the backend, in which case you would send a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request from React to the Java program using clients like [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or the built-in fetch.

The Java program will need to be served on a server or local development server to receive, handle that request, and send a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) response back to React. You can take a look at creating a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) API in Java.